# what are the pros and cons using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

performance ? architecture ? the system in question will always be a MS SQL database there is an existing DAL but there will be refactoring done on the system and Linq-to-SQL seems a good candidate to avoid maintaining a DAL or SP's

Comment: This is very general. You might give us more information about number of tables, procedures, kind of application etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For advantages, see the accepted answer on this related question: [What are the advantages of LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593808/what-are-the-advantages-of-linq-to-sql).

For disadvantages, you may be interested in the discussion at this related question: [linq2sql disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339786/linq2sql-disadvantages)

Comment: thanks, this helped me realize MS sucks again ... deprecating L2S ?! wow im never learning new techs from MS ever again, I'll prob just go back to c/c++ at least it lasted more than 5 years

Comment: @codewrath: L2S isn't deprecated, even in .NET 4. According to the MS guy who came to my workplace when we upgraded to VS2010, MS teams are still supporting and both growing L2S and L2E. Could've been salespeak, of course, but even so, I wouldn't worry about deprecation any time in the immediate future.

Comment: thanks, we're trying to measure the impact of moving towards l2s, but it seems it would be better to just jump straight to EF but it looks like even a more traditional code generator to handle DAL layer might even be better in the long run

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at for a discussion on the pros and cons

http://kevine323.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/linq-to-sql-and-entity-framework-vs.html

-- Lee